# Start script B with ALL variables from script A

Tags: powershell

I've written a powershell script that I run several times a day. It's getting to be somewhat of a chore to execute the script manually (from within Powergui or the shell), so I'd like to create a frontend which prompts me for the variables. I've found that Primalforms can supply me with pre-populated fields that can be adjusted if needed.

My problem is that I would like to create a gui and pass ALL the variables to my external script (this script is already written and will not be part of the Primalforms project).
How would I do this? Or should I pass the variables manually? How would I do that? 
(I do not think this would be specific to Primalforms.. I'm rather executing a script with variables with another script as input.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use splatting. Collect all the values for the parameters in a hashtable (key names match parameter names) and assign each name the value of the parameter from the corresponding text feild in your form. Then pass the hashtable to script B. The following assumes that you have two text fields with names of: filter and path.

```
## scriptA ##

$params = @{
    path=$path.text
    filter=$filter.text
}

D:\Scripts\scriptB.ps1 @params
```

Comment: Thank you for tipsing me about splatting! If anyone wants to read more: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/10/18/use-splatting-to-simplify-your-powershell-scripts.aspx  But how would I go about starting script B from script A with the params?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. To start scruipt B from A, in script A create the hashtable and then pass it to script B (e.g D:\Scripts\scriptB.ps1 @params )